# Create a Dataframe based on ranges of other Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark Dataframe containing ranges of numbers (column start and column end), and a column containing the type of this range.
I want to create a new Dataframe with two columns, the first one lists all ranges (incremented by one), and the second one lists the range's type.
To explain more, this is the input Dataframe :

```
+-------+------+---------+
| start |  end |    type |
+-------+------+---------+
|  10   |  20  | LOW     |
|  21   |  30  | MEDIUM  |
|  31   |  40  | HIGH    |
+-------+------+---------+
```

And this is the desired result :

```
+-------+---------+
| nbr   |    type |
+-------+---------+
|  10   | LOW     |
|  11   | LOW     |
|  12   | LOW     |
|  13   | LOW     |
|  14   | LOW     |
|  15   | LOW     |
|  16   | LOW     |
|  17   | LOW     |
|  18   | LOW     |
|  19   | LOW     |
|  20   | LOW     |
|  21   | MEDIUM  |
|  22   | MEDIUM  |
|   ..  | ...     |
+-------+---------+
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
val data = List((10, 20, "Low"), (21, 30, "MEDIUM"), (31, 40, "High"))

  import spark.implicits._
  val df = data.toDF("start", "end", "type") 
  
  df.withColumn("nbr", explode(sequence($"start", $"end"))).drop("start","end").show(false)
```

**output:**

```
+------+---+
|type  |nbr|
+------+---+
|Low   |10 |
|Low   |11 |
|Low   |12 |
|Low   |13 |
|Low   |14 |
|Low   |15 |
|Low   |16 |
|Low   |17 |
|Low   |18 |
|Low   |19 |
|Low   |20 |
|MEDIUM|21 |
|MEDIUM|22 |
|MEDIUM|23 |
|MEDIUM|24 |
|MEDIUM|25 |
|MEDIUM|26 |
|MEDIUM|27 |
|MEDIUM|28 |
|MEDIUM|29 |
+------+---+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: from functions package : import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ .

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Learn-Hadoop works if you're on Spark 2.4+ .

For older Spark version, consider creating a simple **UDF** to mimic the sequence function:

```
val sequence = udf{ (lower: Int, upper: Int) =>
Seq.iterate(lower, upper - lower + 1)(_ + 1)
}
 
df.withColumn("nbr",explode(sequence($"start",$"end"))).drop("start","end").show(false)
```